# How can I serve static files in Node.js with flatiron/director?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flatiron.js

[flatiron / director](https://github.com/flatiron/director) is an URL router.

Let's say I have a Node.js application with a public folder including static files like public CSS and JS files. How can I serve everything under this directory using director?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the static plugin for Flatiron to serve static files

```
app.use(flatiron.plugins.static, { root: __dirname });
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I decided to use just simply Express. So I don't have to use a flatiron plugin for this.